# База городов: реализация

Tags: php, mysql

Есть **хорошая база городов** — [citieslist.ru](http://citieslist.ru) (по моему копия базы ВКонтакте, но не суть).

Там больше **1 млн. строк**.

**Вопросы:**

1. Как **SQL dump** залить в мою базу (**VPS**)?
2. Как сделать, чтобы выборка производилась очень быстро? Выборка по названиям стран и городов (LIKE наверное).
3. У кого на [**этих строках**](http://src.unotes.ru/s/mitz3qd2mv.png) такие же символы (иероглифы)?

Выборка будет производится для **autocomplete**, а также на страницах пользователей (скорее всего это очень много просмотров в будущем).

Comment: 3.

В неправильной кодировке открываете. Попробуйте открыть в utf-8

Comment: @mantigatos, точно.

Answer (score 1):

1. Если в твоей базе нет таблиц с именами `countries` и `cities`, то можно разворачивать дамп сразу в свою БД. Если таблицы с такими именами есть, то можно создать новую БД `citieslist`, развернуть в нее дамп, а, дальше, запросами типа [`INSERT INTO SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html), перенести данные из `citieslist` в свою БД в нужном виде.
2. Если выборки будут искать по начальному фрагменту, то достаточно проиндексировать поле с названием. Тогда `LIKE` будет использовать индекс. Для быстрой выборки городов по заданной стране нужно проиндексировать поле `country_id` в `cities`.
3. Кодировка БД и кодировка подключения должна быть `utf8`.

Популярные страны и популярные города можно отметить дополнительным полем `is_popular` в обоих таблицах. Их тоже нужно проиндексировать.

Comment: За ответ спасибо, но нового ничего не узнал.

Comment: А что тут может быть нового? ))

Миллион записей это нет так и много. Для быстрых выборок достаточно обычных индексов. Бинарный поиск записи в миллионном списке - это цикл максимум из 20-ти итераций.

Comment: Хм, я не думаю что мой VPS будет быстро обрабатывать такие запросы.

Comment: Тут смысл не в мощности сервера. Это если искать без использования индексов то 10^6 - это очень много, а 10^9 - очень очень много. Бинарный поиск в упорядоченной последовательности будет работать быстро на любом серваке. У него логарифмическая сложность. На ~1000 записей поиск отработает за 10 итераций, на ~1000000 - за 20, на ~1000000000 - за 30. То-есть, практически мгновенно.

Answer (score 0):

1  [Загрузка(импорт) через phpmyadmin (больших файлов)](http://searchcms.ru/site-create/import-large-sql-file-into-mysql-database.html)
2. На вашим месте, я бы создал таблицу для каждой страны,,
3. У меня =). Кодировка не та) (Попробуйте открыть в Utf-8), как сказали в комментариях)

Comment: 1. ок.
2. 270+ таблиц? Как работает это во ВКонтакте-то?

Comment: Вы не сравнивайте сервера, плюс, я думаю, что там не одна таблица. Ваш сайт будет русско язычный верно? Если да, то можно сделать следующие, популярные страны русскоязычные, такие как Россия, Украина, Казахстан..., можно в одну таблицу, а все остальные странны в другую таблицу. Насчет моего первого способа, чем вас смущает?))) Ведь, вы сказали "очень быстро", а как по мне это быстрый вариант =). А да кстати еще можно поле , которое отвечает за id страны в городах проиндексировать)

Comment: Да, сайт будет пока что точно русскоязычный.

Comment: Тогда выберите для популярных стран одна таблица, для остольных другая. Вроде на mail.ru так и идет( Если не ошибаюсь)

Comment: Я думаю может оставить только страны СНГ.

Comment: @Node_pro, там две связанные таблицы: countries и cities. Схема простая как угол дома. Зечем создавать по таблице на страну?! И как потом делать выборки. Переменное имя таблицы в запросе? Глупость.

Индексация и дополнительные поля решают все проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Насчет второго вопроса...

Посмотрите в сторону [nested sets деревьев](http://www.getinfo.ru/article610.html). С этим будет сложнее разобраться (особенно если никогда не сталкивались с деревьями), но, поверьте, это того стоит. Вы получите очень быструю выборку как стран, так и областей, и городов. Можете даже районы привязать. Я сам никогда не использовал такие деревья в базе данных, но по своему хоть и небольшому опыту работы с деревьями (и по совету знакомых) знаю, что это будет только в плюс.

SQL дамп можете залить с помощью специальных программ для работы с базами. Для mysql это Mysql Workbench.

Comment: Пробовал разобраться с nested sets - не получилось (видимо не нужно было). Но у меня есть PHP-класс который производит любые действия с nested sets.

Comment: @exec, попробуйте все-таки еще раз) А поделиться сможете?)

Comment: К сожалению, нет никакого времени заниматься этим в данный момент. Есть куча куда более важных дел на проекте. Что-то класс найти не могу. Найду - отпишу.